# JavaFX Text and TextFlow Constructor Minutia

Tags: javafx, text, textflow

Why does adding to a TextFlow via a Text object constructed with method returning a plain String not work whereas adding to a Textflow via a Text object constructed with a reference to a String does work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It's easier to understand what you're talking about when we can see the code.

Comment: What do you mean by *"plain string"*? A string literal? All values passed to a `String` parameters are either a reference to a `String` object or `null`. String literals are not different.